# Convert row of string dates to array of Date objects

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, date, null

I have a 2d array that contains some nil values.

```
require 'date'
array = [["2014-01-12", "2014-01-12", "2014-01-12"],
          ["2012-08-26", "2012-10-18", nil],
          ["2013-04-09", "2013-05-22", "2013-07-01"]]
```

The desired result is an array of date objects. The resulting array should look like this 
(Date objects for display purposes):

```
changed_array = [#<Date: 2014-01-12 ((2456874j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, nil, #<Date: 2012-07-31 ((2456874j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]
```

I considered something like:

```
changed_array = array.map { |due| (Date.strptime(due[2], "%Y-%m-%d")) unless (due[2] == nil) }
```

Any input is appreciated.

EDIT:

As a newbie to coding I would appreciate any input on alternative approaches to this solution!

Comment: ...it seems that your solution works as well, what's wrong with it in your opinion?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is the difference between `changed_array` and `changed_date`?

Comment: @sawa that was a typo. Have no edited to also include a question. If anyone has an idea why this was given a -1 please let me know why! It is very useful to have input, so thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the last element to be parsed into date you can do the following:

```
changed_date = array.map(&:last).map { |d| Date.parse(d) if d }
# => [#<Date: 2014-01-12 ((2456670j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, nil, #<Date: 2013-07-01 ((2456475j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]
```

The first `map` takes only the last element of each array, and the second parses the date, unless it is `nil`.

Comment: no need two iteration `[array.flatten.map { |d| Date.parse(d) if d }]`

Comment: @Зелёный - in his expected result the OP uses _only_ `due[2]` (the last element of the array)

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Uri's solution, but with only one `map`

```
array.map {|*_, d| Date.parse(d) if d}
# => [#<Date: 2014-01-12 ((2456670j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, nil, #<Date: 2013-07-01 ((2456475j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]
```